# Is it possible to set multiple imports as an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
import {Parser_1} from "./P3K_Parser";
import {Parser_2} from "./Y_Parser";
import {Parser_3} from "./KL_Parser";
```

I would like to run over each parsers

So instead of repeating myself by doing:

```
let parsers = [Parser_1, Parser_2, Parser_3];
```

Then

```
parsers.forEach....
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do something like:

```
let parsers = [
import {Parser_1} from "./P3K_Parser", 
import {Parser_2} from "./Y_Parser",  
import {Parser_3} from "./KL_Parser"];
```

Thanks

Comment: Imports are always things you have to do once, so I don't think it's a problem if you need more lines for them.

Comment: I'm using webpack and that imports may be dynamics following of a json configuration file

Comment: What does your configuration file do here, select the parsers?

Comment: yes, select the parsers to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look into the [Dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) :

```
parsers.forEach(parser => {
   import(parser).then(doSomething);
})
```